# Choosing Field in Python Script Tool using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, python-script-tool

I am writing a script to quickly split large FCs and make them shareable. So I need the tool needs to know what the FC name is and What the Field Name is to split the FC into manageable segments.

To make the Field Name a dropdown would I need to have the user choose a FC and run the tool then have a second tool pop up with the Field Names available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the 'Dependency' property for the field input parameter to be the table input parameter.

See the information under the 'Dependency' heading at:  [Setting Script Tool Parameters](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/setting-script-tool-parameters.htm)